# Is it possible to modify the case of a token inside of a macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I am writing a macro which creates a struct managing user input. I am using the crates [bitflags](https://crates.io/crates/bitflags) and [sdl2](https://crates.io/crates/sdl2). **Return** is an example for the key <kbd>Return</kbd>.

This macro takes a list of all possible inputs and then

```
($($flag:ident = $value:expr;)+)  => { ... }
```

1. Creates a new bitflag with the name of the input

   ```
   bitflags!(
       struct KeyType: u64 {
       $(
           const $flag = $value;// UPPER_CASE is the norm for globals: 'RETURN'
       )+
       }
   );
   ```
2. Checks if the key is pressed, using the [`Keycode`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.30.0/sdl2/keyboard/enum.Keycode.html) enum.

   ```
   match event {
       $(Event::KeyDown { keycode: Some(Keycode::$flag), .. } => { 
           self.flags.insert($flag); 
       },)+
        _ => ()
   }// All enum fields start with a capital letter: 'Return'
   ```
3. Creates a getter function:

   ```
   $(
       pub fn $flag(&self) -> bool { // lower_case is the norm for functions: 'return'
           self.flags.contains($flag)
       }
   )+
   ```

Can I adapt `$flag` to fit all three requirements (`flag`, `Flag`, `FLAG`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macro_rules macros cannot do this. You would need to implement it as a procedural macro, which is allowed to perform arbitrary Rust code to generate the expanded code. In particular, procedural macros are able to call [`str::to_uppercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_uppercase) and [`str::to_lowercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_lowercase).

```
// [dependencies]
// quote = "1.0"
// syn = "1.0"

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::parse::{Parse, ParseStream, Result};
use syn::{parse_macro_input, Expr, Ident, Token};

struct Input {
    flags: Vec<Ident>,
    values: Vec<Expr>,
}

// $( $flag:ident = $value:expr; )*
impl Parse for Input {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let mut flags = Vec::new();
        let mut values = Vec::new();
        while !input.is_empty() {
            flags.push(input.parse()?);
            input.parse::<Token![=]>()?;
            values.push(input.parse()?);
            input.parse::<Token![;]>()?;
        }
        Ok(Input { flags, values })
    }
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn sleeping_panda(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = parse_macro_input!(input as Input);

    let camelcase_flags = &input.flags; // assume CamelCase in the input
    let bitflag_values = &input.values;

    let uppercase_flags = input
        .flags
        .iter()
        .map(|ident| Ident::new(&ident.to_string().to_uppercase(), ident.span()));
    // Some copies because these need to appear multiple times in the generated code.
    let uppercase_flags2 = uppercase_flags.clone();
    let uppercase_flags3 = uppercase_flags.clone();

    let lowercase_flags = input
        .flags
        .iter()
        .map(|ident| Ident::new(&ident.to_string().to_lowercase(), ident.span()));

    TokenStream::from(quote! {
        bitflags::bitflags! (
            struct KeyType: u64 {
                #(
                    const #uppercase_flags = #bitflag_values;
                )*
            }
        );

        pub struct SleepingPanda {
            flags: KeyType,
        }

        impl SleepingPanda {
            pub fn receive_event(&mut self, event: sdl2::event::Event) {
                match event {
                    #(
                        sdl2::event::Event::KeyDown {
                            keycode: Some(sdl2::keyboard::Keycode::#camelcase_flags),
                            ..
                        } => {
                            self.flags.insert(KeyType::#uppercase_flags2);
                        }
                    )*
                    _ => {}
                }
            }

            #(
                pub fn #lowercase_flags(&self) -> bool {
                    self.flags.contains(KeyType::#uppercase_flags3)
                }
            )*
        }
    })
}
```

Using the macro:

```
use sleeping_panda::sleeping_panda;

sleeping_panda! {
    Backspace = 8;
    Tab = 9;
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Why do you have to make multiple copies when it appears multiple times in the generated code? I don't see why `quote!` shouldn't just borrow containers.

Answer (score 15):

The [`paste`](https://github.com/dtolnay/paste) crate helps do identifier case conversions in a macro_rules macro, using `[<$ident:lower>]` for lowercase and `[<$ident:upper>]` for uppercase.

Something like this:

```
// [dependencies]
// paste = "0.1"

macro_rules! sleeping_panda {
    ($($flag:ident = $value:expr;)+) => {
        paste::item! {
            bitflags::bitflags! (
                struct KeyType: u64 {
                    $(
                        const [<$flag:upper>] = $value;
                    )*
                }
            );

            pub struct SleepingPanda {
                flags: KeyType,
            }

            impl SleepingPanda {
                pub fn receive_event(&mut self, event: sdl2::event::Event) {
                    match event {
                        $(
                            sdl2::event::Event::KeyDown {
                                keycode: Some(sdl2::keyboard::Keycode::$flag),
                                ..
                            } => {
                                self.flags.insert(KeyType::[<$flag:upper>]);
                            }
                        )*
                        _ => {}
                    }
                }

                $(
                    pub fn [<$flag:lower>](&self) -> bool {
                        self.flags.contains(KeyType::[<$flag:upper>])
                    }
                )*
            }
        }
    };
}

sleeping_panda! {
    Backspace = 8;
    Tab = 9;
}
```